# Why do we generally see only one person per type of magic?

Tags: fairy-tail

Why do we usually see only one person using a type of magic? Look at Cana's magic for example. Out of everything shown via the Anime, no one else has used it on their own. Same with Reedus, Makarov, Evergreen, Bickslow, Gildarts, Jura, Erza (Knight), and many other people.

I can understand why limited number of people use the rare/lost magic (Dragon Slayer and other lost types), but what about the more modern magics?

Comment: There have been users with the same type of magic (eg Lucy and yukina), but from a reader's point of view it would be rather boring to see the same type of magic over and over again (cfr All the different dragon-roars are basically the same attack), so I think plotwise it would make more sense to stick to different types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Episode 222 of the Anime, Lucy want to learn transformation magic from Mirajane (and some others join in).

So it is possible but really hard and requires a large effort than mastering his own type of magic. Besides it was too complicated for her.

It is like talent. Additionally not all types of magic are accessible to everyone because of missing prerequisites, such as dragon slayer and god slayer magic, which requires an dragon teaching an infant from the beginning or a lacrima crystal implant.

There are also magic wilders like Rufus Lore who creates new spells based on those he memorizes. Although one might argue that it's his magic which allows him doing so.