# Can wizards/magic users possess more than one type of magic?

Tags: fairy-tail

I've noticed that in Fairy Tail everyone has a different type of magic. But would it be possible to possess more than one type of magic? For example: Natsu being able to use Fire Dragon Slayer Magic and and also being able to use Magic like Gray's Ice-Make spells? Or are there rules for his Dragon Slayer Magic not allowing him to use different kinds of Magic?

Comment: I don't think so. I don't remember there being many magicians with super different abilities. Also the head master does have the power of giants and the ability to wipe all foes away. Does that count?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20478/6166

Comment: Natsu later gains laxus's lightning dragon lockera and becomes a lightning/fire dragon slayer

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they can. The best example is [Makarov Dreyar](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Makarov_Dreyar), Fairy Tail's 3rd and 6th master. He can master many different types of magics:

> - Fairy Law
> - Fire Magic
> - Ice Magic
> - Light Magic
> - Maximum Defense Seal
> - Requip
> - Titan
> - Wind Magic
> - Dispelling Magic
> - Telepathy

Another example is Ultear. She originally learned Time magic and later learned Ice magic to kill her mother. **Magic isn't something you are born with, it is something you can learn.** So you can learn multiple magics, but with anything in life, if you stick to only one skill and train it with everything you got, you will become more profound in it, than if you divide your time between different skills.